# Can anybody explain what is parameters $\eta$ and L in graphene 2D polarizability formula?

Tags: graphene

Sorry. Can anybody explain what is parameters eta and L in the graphene 2D [image: polarizability] formula  I have attached bellow. this formula is from the paper "Dielectric function, screening, and plasmons in two-dimensional graphene" by E. H. Hwang and S. Das Sarma.
I would be appreciated for any help.

Comment: It is very difficult to provide insight into a mathematical expression without any context.  Can you discuss the problem and indicate where is your conceptual difficulty?  In particular, something as basic as explaining what is $\Pi$?

Answer (score 0):

$\eta$ is a positive infinitesimal.  It is present to make sure that contour integrations are closed to contain the correct poles in the complex plane.  It is present is all kinds of similar formulas, although it is often written as $\epsilon.$

I think that $L$ is just the linear dimension of the sample.  It may be present because of the use of an unconventional normalization of the sum.  The fact that the formula uses a discrete sum over intermediate states *and* and $i\eta$ prescription (normally reserved for integrals) bolsters this interpretation.